# Parallel and VMWare tools for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, vmware, parallels

I have both Parallels and VMWare (Fusion) where I'd like to use a Ubuntu 12.04 image but unfortunately in both I have a very similar situation ... I can't seem to access the drive that has the tools on it.

In both cases the virtualisation software *thinks* it has mounted the drive and in fact the OS seems to very mildly agree. I say agree because you can navigate to the `/dev/disk/by-label/` and find `VMWare\x20Tools` and `Parallels\x20Tools`. If you look at where they're pointing, in both cases you'll find they point to `../../sr0`. Ok great, so if I do an `ls` of `../../sr0` what do I get? Nothing.

I've also gone through each of the mounting points on `/media` not to mention all the "cdrom" and "dvd" entries in `/dev`.

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 1):

i did:

sudo mount -o exec /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom

and this mounted parallel tools in /media/cdrom (provided that parallel tools .iso was being mounted in the vm settings).

then sudo /media/cdrom/install works